Power BI - Get slicers to mirror data from the same period of the previous selected year
I have a table visual containing the individual quatation entries made by each broker.
Firstly, I wanted it to display the data from the same period of the previous year based on the selection made in my date slicers. For that, I created a measure that calculates the amount of estimated premium using SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR and added it to my table visual, as per below:
GWP Estimado - Ano Anterior = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(bi_prospect_analysis_kpw[estimated_premium]),
        SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendário'[Date])
    )

This worked perfectly.
The issue with this is, once I add slicers to my dashboard, the slicers won't be mirroring the data of the same period of the last year, which is a huge issue.
Any way to make it so my slicers actually mirror the data of the same period last year?

Can you provide some data ?
